# HTML: Float inside of a float

Tags: html, css

So i have my header setup fine. Then i have my body. What i want to happen is to have the body split (did that fine, no problem). then on the left side i have my navigation and the right side i have my main body content. My problem is if i use a float for the initial split how do i split the right side in half then? I want 3 sections overall. Left side, then leftRight and rightRight.

My question is, can i put a float inside something this is already floating? If so, then how? if not, then how can i split the right side of my body again?

Here is what i tried: http://people.eecs.ku.edu/~ageoffri/unavitSite/

Comment: Did you try it? (hint: you can)

Comment: To answer your question. Yes you can float something inside of something that is already floating. However if you provide some HTML/ CSS or a jsFiddle we can answer the question better.

Comment: Yes i did try it, with no success. Never used jsFiddle before. lemme try it out and ill get back to you.

Comment: In the page you put up, you didn't put #leftRight and #rightRight inside #right. Try doing that.

Comment: HAHA! classic misplaced /div :( THank you very much! put that as an answer and ill accept it lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can put floating elements inside other floating elements.

As you discovered, your code has a misplaced div, so you aren't actually nesting your elements.